# Add <br /> tag after end of every line in jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<textarea>` field for user input. I want this -
When user paste their text in that field and click some button it will automatic add a line break tag `<br />` after the end of every line.
My html form look like this.

```html
<div class="comment">
    <textarea class="form-control page_details" rows="5" id="text" placeholder="Detail here" name="details"></textarea>
    <button type="button">Generate</button>
</div>
```

and when user paste their text on textarea field like.

> **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
>
>   consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
>
>   sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
>
>   ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
>
>   erat volutpat.**

When clicking the button it will look like this.

> **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, `<br />`
>
>   consectetuer adipiscing elit, `<br />`
>
>   sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt`<br />`
>
>   ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam`<br />`
>
>   erat volutpat.`<br />`**

Help me out guys.

Comment: does your input have carriage return when you have copy pasted it in text-area? Or do you want `generate` button to compute line size and insert break-line automatically?

Comment: any method will do. clicking generate is easy to  understand for me.

Comment: Read my question again. Most of the answers below are assuming (because of your ambigious input) that input already has line feed (`\n`) character in it. Is your input a single line which you want to break into multiple based on the width of textarea or does it already have required line feed characters?

Comment: User will copy and paste content from website. So that input already has line feed (\n) character in it. Yes it is. and i wanted to convert it as html line break tag <br>.
Thanks again. It solved. some one solved in code snipped.

Comment: <?=nl2br($content)?> is the easiest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `String.protototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/\n|\s\n/` , `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `"<br>\n"` , concatenate `"<br>"` to end of replacement `textarea` `value`

```js
function addBreak(el) {
  var textarea = el;
  var matches = textarea.value.split(/\n|\s\n/);
  textarea.value = matches.join("<br>\n") + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <textarea class="form-control page_details" rows="5" id="text" placeholder="Detail here" name="details"></textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="addBreak(this.previousElementSibling)">Generate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! thanks for the solution. This is extraordinary. Works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use on paste event.

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
  $("#text").bind("paste", function(e){
    $('#txtarea').append('<BR>').focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="comment">
    <textarea class="form-control page_details" rows="5" id="text" placeholder="Detail here" name="details"></textarea>
    <button type="button">Generate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd cover my bets by handling `\r\n` (the sequence), and then handling `\r`and `\n` through a character class, like this:

```
text = text.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br />').replace(/[\r\n]/g, '<br />');
```

The first replace turns the sequence `\r\n` into `<br />`. The second replace replaces any `\r` or `\n` characters found on their own with the string.

More on regular expressions in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the new line characters with `<br/>`

```
var pastedText = $("#text").val();
pastedText = pastedText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br>");
```